# Segmentation fault with cray pointers and arrays: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My code is complicated but the following MWE Fortran program shows the problem and results in a segmentation fault in Intel Fortran 18.0.5.

```
     forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

the traceback shows problem occurred during malloc() call on `NN= malloc(nsize)`

It also results in the following error with gfortran

```
    ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000603b40 ***
```

The source code is:

```
      program test
  c         this program tests memory allocation

      read(*,*)k
      call  test_cray(k)
      end

      subroutine test_cray(k)
  #ifdef BIT64
      integer*8 NN, nsize
  #endif
      real x(*)
      real*8 prob(k,k, 128, 128)
      real*8 prob1(k,k, 128, 128)
      real*8 prob2(k,k, 128, 128)
      pointer(NN , x)
      nsize =   k*4*128*128
      nsize =20
      NN= malloc(nsize)
      do i =1, 20
      x(i)=0.1*(i-1)
      end do
      NN =loc(x)
      write(*,*) NN
      !write(*,*) "shape of x=", shape(x)
      call shape_cray(NN)
      write(*,*)"shape_cray returned"
      end
      subroutine shape_cray(NN )
      real y
        pointer(nx , y)

     do i =1, 20
        nx = NN + (i-1)*4
         write(*,*)nx,  y
     end do

      write(*,*) NN
      write(*,*) "shape of y=", shape(y)
      write(*,*) "y=", y
      end
```

Note that the spaces in the program had to be adjusted for markdown. What is the right way to do this without the segmentation fault?

Here is the output:

```
    prompt> ifort -g -O0 -traceback -DBIT64 -mcmodel=large cray_test1.F
    prompt> ./a.out
      128
      forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
      Image              PC                Routine            Line   Source 
      libifcoremt.so.5   00007F70F617F49C  for__signal_handl Unknown  Unknown
      libpthread-2.12.s  00000034A2C0F790      Unknown      Unknown  Unknown
      a.out              0000000000400C3B  test_cray_                 19  cray_test1.F
    a.out              000000000040097D  MAIN__          5  cray_test1.F
    a.out              00000000004008CE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
    libc-2.12.so       00000034A241ED5D  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
    a.out              00000000004007D9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I used `k=120`.

Comment: Is there any reason at all that you can't use standard Fortran to do this? Allocatable arrays would be so much easier than the quarter of a century out of date, non-standard stuff that you are trying to use.

Comment: So what is the **complete** output? Where does it stop? Which lines you still get printed? What is the purpose of `NN =loc(x)`?

Comment: @IanBush I am trying to improve an old code that manages memory manually. There is just too much code that I would need to change in order to make F90 and have failed previously and given up

Comment: @VladimirF loc(x) retrieves the address of x. I will add the output. Maybe an expert like you can explain what is going on

Comment: Try compiling your code with -Wall with gfortran.  Once you fix the warning/errors.  You may have better luck getting a result you want.  As an added bonus you have committed the cardinal sin of implicit typing.  Add `IMPLICIT NONE`.

Comment: @steve, what makes you think this is a implicit none problem? I did it as well as `-Wall` and the result did not change

Comment: For the posted code, did you fix all of the warning and errors?  Try adding -fimplict-none and ask yourself if the implicit interfaces are a good idea.  Compiling with and without -DBIT64, I get for line 26 `Error: Type mismatch in argument 'nn' at (1); passed INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4)`

Comment: It looks like the gfortran intrinsic `MALLOC` function a default integer argument whereas the C `malloc` function wants `integer(C_SIZE_T)` by value. If you want the latter function you could write up an interface block for `malloc`. And definitely subroutine needs to declare dummy argument `NN` as `integer(C_INTPTR_T)`.

Comment: @user5713492, where did you get that info concerning `MALLOC`?  gfortran's documentation seems to disgree with you: _The return value is of type_ `INTEGER(K)`, _with_ `K` _such that variables of type_ `INTEGER(K)` _have the same size as C pointers_  `sizeof(void *)`.  At best it's target dependent, and on 64-bit OS's that will map to `INTEGER(8)`

Comment: @evets You are reading about the result of `MALLOC`, not the `SIZE=` dummy argument. Subroutine shape_cray is faulty because it doesn't declare dummy argument `NN` for sure.

Comment: @evets I guess I misread the gfortran documentation in that when it says the type of the `SIZE=` argument shall be INTEGER it meant that any KIND is allowed. A test program confirms this because gfortran accepts KINDs 1, 2, 3, 8, and 16 as actual arguments.

Comment: @user5713492, admittedly the docs could be a bit clearer.  The gist is that gfortran selects the integer with a size that matches the size of a C address on the target.  The problem with the code is the implicit interfaces do not allow argument checking.  PS: I did not write gfortran's cray pointer.  I simply reviewed the patch and okay its inclusion into GCC.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "Do not use Cray pointers.  Use allocatable entities".  But given that one might be working with and updating legacy code.  This fixes your example and modernizes the code.  Note, I did not use `contains` subprograms nor provide interface statements.  So, you still have implicit interfaces.

```
  program test
     implicit none
     integer k
     read(*,*) k
     if (k > 0) call test_cray(k)
  end

  subroutine test_cray(k)

     use iso_c_binding, only : c_intptr_t

     implicit none

     integer, intent(in) :: k

     integer(c_intptr_t) nn
     integer i, nsize
     real x(*)
     pointer(nn, x)

     nsize = k
     nn = malloc(nsize)
     x(1:nsize) = 0.1 * [(i - 1, i = 1, nsize)]
     nn = loc(x)
     write(*,*) nn

     call shape_cray(nn, nsize)

  end subroutine test_cray

  subroutine shape_cray(nn, nsize)

     use iso_c_binding, only : c_intptr_t

     implicit none

     integer(c_intptr_t), intent(in) :: nn
     integer, intent(in) :: nsize

     real y
     integer i
     pointer(nx, y)

     do i = 1, nsize
        nx = nn + (i - 1) * 4  ! Assumes REAL is 4 bytes.
        write(*,*) nx, y
     end do

     write(*,*) nn
     write(*,*) "shape of y = ", shape(y)
     write(*,*) "y = ", y
  end subroutine shape_cray
```

With gfortran this gives

```
gfcx -o z -fcray-pointer a.f
./z
2
671645728
671645728   0.00000000    
671645732  0.100000001    
671645728
shape of y = 
y =   0.100000001
```